# App get Rejected: crashes on launch , but worked fine for me on all devices as well

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5, xcode6

My app is for the iPhone only .And it is working fine on all devices but when submitted the app it get rejected by apple by saying .......

On 1st time submission

```
We found your app crashed on launch so we were unable to review it.

Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing, and that it runs as expected, before resubmitting.
```

this the crash report link please
[this is the crash report](http://a828.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/fd/12/16/fd121669-2df7-37b9-881f-8f105d56f198/temp..jvujurcl.crash?downloadKey3=1423926097_295b481b936768422e5c5998a0b7dfbe)

[crash report](http://a738.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/eb/b4/31/ebb4310a-d345-24a5-9cf6-00beab8c02fc/temp..sjlgamxu.crash?downloadKey3=1423926097_0a39b4f9aee334608cc07ac14ce270c9)

on second submission it get rejected  they says

```
Thank you for your resubmission. However, we were still unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Specifically, upon review we found the application will shortly crash after launch.
```

they send crash report

[on second time submission](http://a695.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/b8/f1/bc/b8f1bc31-45af-0873-38e0-5f41f851dce1/temp..acadxdjs.crash?downloadKey3=1423926097_7aa9dbfab94e47943df89e9e88fb8ea0)

[on second time submission](http://a1301.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/f2/8e/cb/f28ecba9-723f-802d-ea8d-4db44fea9d84/temp..bkknldlt.crash?downloadKey3=1423926097_333efc905006e065c943a87fd6843143)

I didn't get where i am doing wrong ,please check this ,Thanks in advance

I also try Bhavin step to find the crash location but terminal show's me like that

[image]

Comment: Did you [analyze the crash reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)?

Comment: @jcm My app running well on all device,I  didn't find the crash on my device

Comment: Your terminal command is telling you it can't find the path. Check Users/developmentmedia ... your user account is called developmentmedia.

Comment: atos: No such file or directory

Comment: @harish It looks like you don't understand what the terminal command you tried to use actually does or how to use it. Firstly, you shouldn't blindly copy and paste terminal commands without making an effort to understand what it does and how to use it - do some research or you could end up risking data loss.

Comment: Secondly, you have no space between cd and /Users so the terminal thinks you're trying to run a command that doesn't exist (because no command exists called cd/Users/etc/etc

Comment: Finally, you need to replace MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH with the actual memory address of the crashing line from the crash report, eg. 0x1000e0000.

Please do some research and understand what you're being instructed to do and don't just copy and paste things.

Comment: finally I know how to read the crash report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. We can just directly drag and drop the crash-report on the device log.
Then it will convert the crash report into readable format.

STEPS:

1. Attach your device to mac.
2. Open Xcode
3. Goto **window** from menu bar
4. Click on **devices** like this

[image]

5. Now, drag and drop your crash report you received from apple. It will symbolicate it and show you in readable format. If the file extension is .txt, change it to ".crash".

Comment: Remember to select "All logs" in order to see also the crash reports sent by Apple that you dragged in..

Comment: Note that Apple will give you .txt crash files, and you'll need to change the extension to .crash. I just suggested an edit.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps :

> 1. Get the **.ipa** file that you submitted to the app store.
> 2. Rename the extention **.ipa** with **.zip** , extract it. You'll get a *Payload Folder* which contains **.app** file.
> 3. Create a folder with this **.app** file and **crash log** file.
> 4. Now, open **terminal** application and go to the folder created in above step (using `cd` command).
> 5. Run this magic line :
>
>    `atos -arch armv7 -o YourAppName.app/YourAppName MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH`
>
> Where, `MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH` = location where your app crashed as
>   per the  report.

It'll give you the *exact line*, *method name* which resulted in crash.

Comment: I try but not get the location please check the terminal report
please check above question over there past the terminal image

Comment: It's notable that the crash log states that the code type is `arm64` (`Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)`) - so it's probably required to change the `-arch` value from `armv7` to `arm64`

Answer (score 3):

If you test your app and it works fine but Apple keeps rejecting it then you need to test it on release mode not debug mode as follows:

Edit scheme > Run > Build configuration > release

Hope this helps someone because I came across this issue and it took me too long to sort it out!