# crash report EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, crash-reports

My app is rejected with the reason of "We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch" and sent me crash report also, i tested my app on all the possible device but i can't able to reproduce this issue.

Can anybody help me how can i fix this my issue.

```
Incident Identifier: 6A6F574E-5071-4009-89FD-BD0B92C5E0FF
CrashReporter Key:   2977b2ca2b0a157c0cbb98cbe60bd58df34b0499
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Odoo HRM [4030]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D341FB0E-30F5-4FB2-83F9-15003425BBE9/Odoo HRM.app/Odoo HRM
Identifier:          com.serpentcs.OdooHRM
Version:             1.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-08 19:34:22.230 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-08 19:34:22.126 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1853082d8 0x196a280e4 0x185308218 0x186171a28 0x1000252d0 0x189d48c84 0x189d48994 0x189d4f1d0 0x189d4c880 0x189dbe8ec 0x189fd2a94 0x189fd5208 0x189fd3778 0x18d9e93c8 0x1852c027c 0x1852bf384 0x1852bd9a8 0x1851e92d4 0x189db443c 0x189daefac 0x10004cb20 0x1970a6a08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971bf270 0x1971a4000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019725d16c 0x197258000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197136b14 0x1970d4000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001961f5414 0x1961f4000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196214b88 0x1961f4000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000196a283bc 0x196a20000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196211bb0 0x1961f4000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196211738 0x1961f4000 + 120632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000196a28290 0x196a20000 + 33424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851e9380 0x1851e0000 + 37760
10  UIKit                           0x0000000189db4438 0x189d38000 + 508984
11  UIKit                           0x0000000189daefa8 0x189d38000 + 487336
12  Odoo HRM                        0x000000010004cb1c 0x100014000 + 232220
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001970a6a04 0x1970a4000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971a4c24 0x1971a4000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197089e6c 0x197078000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019707b998 0x197078000 + 14744

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971a4e48 0x1971a4000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197087f3c 0x197078000 + 65340
2   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d9e9384 0x18d9d0000 + 103300
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197079990 0x197078000 + 6544
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197079950 0x197078000 + 6480
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001970840a0 0x197078000 + 49312
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019707ca58 0x197078000 + 19032
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197086314 0x197078000 + 58132
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197087c48 0x197078000 + 64584
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197259228 0x197258000 + 4648
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197258eec 0x197258000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971bfc78 0x1971a4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972592d8 0x197258000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197258eec 0x197258000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971bfc78 0x1971a4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972592d8 0x197258000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197258eec 0x197258000 + 3820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001971bfc78 0x1971a4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972592d8 0x197258000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197258eec 0x197258000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001740f0db7
    x4: 0x0000000196215dfd   x5: 0x000000016fdeb420   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019b00f310  x21: 0x000000019aff7ce8  x22: 0x000000017415b340  x23: 0x00000001976c5f50
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x000000017415b330  x26: 0x000000019aff60a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fdeb380   lr: 0x000000019725d170
    sp: 0x000000016fdeb360   pc: 0x00000001971bf270 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100014000 - 0x100087fff Odoo HRM arm64  <74be5c64184233ed9ffcfe2b3c668dba> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D341FB0E-30F5-4FB2-83F9-15003425BBE9/Odoo HRM.app/Odoo HRM
0x12001c000 - 0x120043fff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183ab4000 - 0x183c48fff AVFoundation arm64  <c69cb19d6db0339bbfb4c18fa7f4f26c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x183c4c000 - 0x183cb0fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <fdd31b28c0ec3f76b8f0fa9a057e43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x183cf4000 - 0x183cf4fff Accelerate arm64  <a2161063fee1315193bc488d0354f43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x183d0c000 - 0x183f2bfff vImage arm64  <74eb7b77dbcd321db86e784be9353a08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x183f2c000 - 0x183fd3fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <56e8b79c2c03379dad45fe2ea1a4052f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x183fd4000 - 0x18434efff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <fd491ae19b12315babb621650a0eef76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x184350000 - 0x184365fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <9307063a5e1833abbb857a9ec4c5369e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x184368000 - 0x1843d0fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <d4d2b4a941213e2b81f3ddafd6b8a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1843d4000 - 0x1843f7fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <92a0dd635be43dfe8c128c888ef37c0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1843f8000 - 0x1843f8fff vecLib arm64  <9248f57f1d8430219a810aa93254f157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1843fc000 - 0x18442bfff Accounts arm64  <4199851056d4376aa4d8668b83c85454> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x184430000 - 0x1844aefff AddressBook arm64  <73735c2a294139e5b99ada613fc861ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x1844b0000 - 0x184603fff AddressBookUI arm64  <860bc29210ba3d7c80dc83a83388e31c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x1847cc000 - 0x184a8cfff AudioToolbox arm64  <760c2dc59fa13660a769cc1b052d41e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x184c2c000 - 0x184e3ffff CFNetwork arm64  <df5535d1633f375aa889f755db0a93b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x184e40000 - 0x184edcfff CloudKit arm64  <c24c6a0eeb1a38b598fafc24e9974595> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x184ee0000 - 0x184f45fff CoreAudio arm64  <b85ca2cdb29639ccb5f6405baf597027> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x184f6c000 - 0x184f8dfff CoreBluetooth arm64  <fbd7cbc4b2533ea38844bf98757ce58d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x184f90000 - 0x1851dcfff CoreData arm64  <af13d4e830e13607b745fe57f90e5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1851e0000 - 0x18553efff CoreFoundation arm64  <6548b13bef1f3f958d96266f7c4c44e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x185540000 - 0x1856a2fff CoreGraphics arm64  <92162d42d08d357ab66302a38d724828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1856f8000 - 0x1856fafff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <8f40b7d9b97b344f9c7a5a0b79bdc2b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x1856fc000 - 0x185707fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <a40d7bdbbe6c3317bcf4c20c085df848> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x1858fc000 - 0x18591afff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <975284709e51353690ec8a651b43c1db> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x18591c000 - 0x185a4efff CoreImage arm64  <d7a2122dc8173803bc220fde3cfebfdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x185a50000 - 0x185aaefff CoreLocation arm64  <a166ad7f12f93406b54ae6a170fb38ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x185ae8000 - 0x185babfff CoreMedia arm64  <403a9798401c3b70a207e0e236454c0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x185bac000 - 0x185c9afff CoreMotion arm64  <61338e072f2a385ab4e315975f23eea2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x185c9c000 - 0x185d0dfff CoreTelephony arm64  <d9adf384d64d30319eac8e8711ede892> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x185d10000 - 0x185e18fff CoreText arm64  <4a9633cee0393585a98fcf07410e0828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x185e1c000 - 0x185e39fff CoreVideo arm64  <217e5b69f6d03f8893f01de3e40915a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x185e3c000 - 0x185f60fff EventKit arm64  <f7af75b17dac3c5aa8dc91a1edd1df37> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x186114000 - 0x18636cfff Foundation arm64  <509b484fb7b634b19673d50296d8278f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1863a0000 - 0x1863c9fff GSS arm64  <3dae218853563b1a985b80d6a353bad8> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x1864b4000 - 0x18651ffff IOKit arm64  <311bed1f2b893195b8c0564d8925bfa2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x186520000 - 0x1867c3fff ImageIO arm64  <7d3c81746f2c3f1488b3efc633d21633> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1867c4000 - 0x186c65fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <1ad0ed311f3e3897bac70f3388fc05be> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1875a0000 - 0x1875a6fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4e3e82a2b09a38fcbf01843f97d5e604> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1875a8000 - 0x1877cbfff MediaPlayer arm64  <fb0500c5695c36b5b54865f533cc899e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x1877cc000 - 0x187beafff MediaToolbox arm64  <c2103a7dd16e3f67abfe898b039061e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x187bec000 - 0x187cc0fff MessageUI arm64  <000bbe6f4a8c32bda9c8ea674a7f200d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x187cc4000 - 0x187d3cfff Metal arm64  <eb54636e26cd3dee870fa5e4fb708fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x187d40000 - 0x187df1fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <daa61b358c17365792c20df791224e26> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18906c000 - 0x189076fff OpenGLES arm64  <8824bb82d43937a9b0aa3870ece35772> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18907c000 - 0x18907dfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <34760639fb2331dcaa229ba0e418c1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x189080000 - 0x189083fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6f967504d5937d59223598de12969ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x189084000 - 0x189088fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <30969b8fde9f36c4a6a0293c03e74e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18908c000 - 0x189096fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <5942ea8060c63e86b3ffbfb76b061276> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x189098000 - 0x1890e3fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <3e46a6b44be93e5689e4851c76b2db04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x189680000 - 0x189812fff QuartzCore arm64  <e47923f08f343c3e98e77f22f674f234> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x189814000 - 0x189860fff QuickLook arm64  <c7ce94fecae33d839b804000f2ecca60> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x189a98000 - 0x189aecfff Security arm64  <80b60ba1feba39afb6686e342398cce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x189cc0000 - 0x189d33fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <633d8a8abeaf3abda9b0401146f2b668> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x189d38000 - 0x18a6b8fff UIKit arm64  <f67965f71974303e90cfaed997ae36a3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18a6bc000 - 0x18a735fff VideoToolbox arm64  <1468c96c3448370bbb407644bedbb368> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18a770000 - 0x18a9d4fff WebKit arm64  <5e03a0bc7ab436ba900562cceb681ef4> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x18adfc000 - 0x18ae09fff AOSNotification arm64  <bfc45391892b3510ac92ba9362e5100c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x18afa4000 - 0x18b002fff AccountsDaemon arm64  <e819e315efce3a178391a7dfbee95db0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x18b02c000 - 0x18b031fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <cfa106cd07b430a6959f9127a6c3363a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18b234000 - 0x18b237fff AirPlaySupport arm64  <9379098c9eed33088c7096882eec570d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x18b48c000 - 0x18b4d4fff AppSupport arm64  <d088c6263b4932aebd9dcf2a14aadef2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18b4d8000 - 0x18b533fff AppleAccount arm64  <0374ffa0f0563b108aa7a58f2c72f39f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x18b644000 - 0x18b690fff AppleJPEG arm64  <621fe1223e9038a09023dd6c558ce423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18b6a4000 - 0x18b6b8fff ApplePushService arm64  <38b2aec9a5b5357aa8e1060d28992da3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x18b6bc000 - 0x18b6c5fff AppleSRP arm64  <8f0cacbeabdf39b3815a72e7ec9e8668> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x18b6d8000 - 0x18b6e3fff AssertionServices arm64  <e0f182c7fdcd34a1a4acfe0bd4c7eae3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18b6e4000 - 0x18b701fff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <e28e74aed7103573b9416e016525ac04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x18b704000 - 0x18b744fff AssistantServices arm64  <f8cc50774cbf3007bd3944592b1608e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x18b780000 - 0x18b783fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <ea2ff306f28638ca8bc7a4f02d3c8f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x18b784000 - 0x18b7a0fff BackBoardServices arm64  <ff372ac34d6430829a97778caad5bdf4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18b7a8000 - 0x18b7e5fff BaseBoard arm64  <ab16c3464cfb3319bf31202639bb4a90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18b808000 - 0x18b838fff Bom arm64  <45c2562173063fb2bd0e71bbc3423915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x18b944000 - 0x18b974fff CalendarFoundation arm64  <ce2278a234d0300a8e1c55d93179a8ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarFoundation.framework/CalendarFoundation
0x18bac0000 - 0x18bacafff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <0f8d341d0a8f3828b9485b189d04e126> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x18bad8000 - 0x18bc24fff Celestial arm64  <0b8842c85d7139848f5e049e8e784c47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18bc58000 - 0x18bc5efff CertUI arm64  <5172b3a96c1736b390833483c0832e79> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x18bdc4000 - 0x18bde8fff ChunkingLibrary arm64  <d38656203ca635b883d96b9c82d4cb59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x18c394000 - 0x18c3e2fff ColorSync arm64  <af03d31eeea73ffda8259033308781de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18c3e4000 - 0x18c3e6fff CommonAuth arm64  <f6c3ca737c12362baa27b4d67391b85d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/CommonAuth
0x18c3e8000 - 0x18c3fafff CommonUtilities arm64  <cf917a1cdf503940a9879dda3ea7eae4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18c3fc000 - 0x18c400fff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <f57b126af38139b280188f1e33ae77a2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x18c48c000 - 0x18c491fff ConstantClasses arm64  <b1cc336c6ea1319f8131623918110a89> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18c494000 - 0x18c4d2fff ContentIndex arm64  <11771c1154c63b2ea6b3a2759116f76a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x18c4d4000 - 0x18c4dcfff CoreAUC arm64  <ac7f4428bde93a379e4710ff07f8cd82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18c510000 - 0x18c570fff CoreDAV arm64  <0eb42897b04c35558a55ac357b4f4eb5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDAV.framework/CoreDAV
0x18c574000 - 0x18c59cfff CoreDuet arm64  <2325864ac79931d08384cad9a5c2378c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x18c5a8000 - 0x18c5bbfff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <8e9b82e37ab1398fb75be0114863b188> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x18c5c4000 - 0x18c5c6fff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <9a52d10bde253ae196a436618e6245af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18c8a8000 - 0x18c958fff CorePDF arm64  <48261152791832da9b786ccb6e676ce4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x18c9cc000 - 0x18c9d7fff CoreRecents arm64  <cd48e7d3e01439e1b592864083e40954> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRecents.framework/CoreRecents
0x18ccf8000 - 0x18cd8cfff CoreUI arm64  <8e5f6e68de253eb98752939e94219aa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18cd90000 - 0x18ce2afff CoreUtils arm64  <835930892f3f3c28823421061c40dad7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18ce2c000 - 0x18ce32fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <939d8e00b1a8388eaf6721fe6fed8d07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18ce34000 - 0x18ce3afff DAAPKit arm64  <996db669e80833e0a44db31c6e094693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18ce48000 - 0x18ce97fff DataAccess arm64  <7024476be74c3c1d9d7958544753e6d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x18d0f4000 - 0x18d11afff DataAccessExpress arm64  <ba41527f2d0136f787281ddbbe9d2015> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18d16c000 - 0x18d173fff DataMigration arm64  <ac8e9c98ebaf3b3facc8a35d4a5f662d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18d190000 - 0x18d191fff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <446ae998ec433acdac17d08dfb63094d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18d194000 - 0x18d1b4fff DictionaryServices arm64  <d911eb3e1549338d8a3da77f3cf030ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18d1dc000 - 0x18d202fff EAP8021X arm64  <6201a1545ea735eaa654e6c4f19fce9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18d330000 - 0x18d332fff FTClientServices arm64  <41e3fe196535314d955d8adf52731b2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x18d334000 - 0x18d366fff FTServices arm64  <063fb60e8c3031189f047aaf77127419> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x18d368000 - 0x18d795fff FaceCore arm64  <6c9c849bf1173e1892729204b96c95bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18d7cc000 - 0x18d7ccfff FontServices arm64  <9d2ca68913c53fef976aabcdb3f2bb7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18d7d0000 - 0x18d8b0fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <3e696fd5c611305eaee6bad27362f029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18d8b4000 - 0x18d8c3fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <c98491fefd2a34f5a1a5fab3cce3d478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x18d9d0000 - 0x18d9f0fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <06e8a3da46443f858df92288b8b009bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18e598000 - 0x18e5b1fff GenerationalStorage arm64  <c02d99b6f6e138249504e2a9a598e9b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x18e5b4000 - 0x18e8c9fff GeoServices arm64  <624b0528e79e3bd78cf8e4ca477e207b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x18e8cc000 - 0x18e8dffff GraphicsServices arm64  <75b91070a0e7388fb904347f318b8cc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18e9dc000 - 0x18ea44fff Heimdal arm64  <d7f823808ea338e189ab8f504eccb3a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Heimdal
0x18eb58000 - 0x18ebf2fff HomeSharing arm64  <9d9df9ed1dc53162a89400f3c5a786df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x18ecc8000 - 0x18ecf6fff IDSFoundation arm64  <9411f337675431bd9d1ee6ca7f2e9810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x18eedc000 - 0x18ef4dfff IMFoundation arm64  <49f257517bed3c80a505c395449ab8a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x18ef58000 - 0x18ef5ffff IOAccelerator arm64  <95ab3e3274d630779faccf8902ddc494> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18ef64000 - 0x18ef6afff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <079c9947522f331b8837714ca08e0966> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x18ef6c000 - 0x18ef72fff IOSurface arm64  <202149d941b339f1a765e48058a523ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18ef74000 - 0x18ef76fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <9aaea96dbea43a648fa78e7f43f769cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18f034000 - 0x18f03bfff IntlPreferences arm64  <0ba4276ecf8831378d3576dd145e3282> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
0x18f03c000 - 0x18f081fff LanguageModeling arm64  <f484305f34db38e7be02f5cd0b37404b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x18f0c8000 - 0x18f110fff MIME arm64  <692dce99d89d32298da32bbde8c18a63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x18f114000 - 0x18f180fff MMCS arm64  <780e63b11aeb3997b5bafb50d6b21b03> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x18f1e4000 - 0x18f1f2fff MailServices arm64  <61cef8e55a8f3747b5adeecb2f430e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x18f230000 - 0x18f2eefff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <b8ba68326c7030c1803e9f01edcefe02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x18f300000 - 0x18f301fff Marco arm64  <f08df1984df33a7c80d2a2d9f8537c71> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x18f304000 - 0x18f388fff MediaControlSender arm64  <efb209af426c3d2bb592c4e8f2648a27> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x18f43c000 - 0x18f454fff MediaRemote arm64  <29897add26cf34f7b92dc012ed32f883> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x18f458000 - 0x18f46dfff MediaServices arm64  <98515a962b2f335da9efb5f14931c42f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaServices.framework/MediaServices
0x18f50c000 - 0x18f609fff Message arm64  <2b6c7c4d05c23c12add40cc85a849458> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x18f614000 - 0x18f617fff MessageSupport arm64  <9852ca056bd13fb1b1d9254aa015cc3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x18f628000 - 0x18f637fff MobileAsset arm64  <b09857caa4663e268cbf77652e40c7df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x18f6a4000 - 0x18f6adfff MobileInstallation arm64  <096c77b57b62337bb756b2b347fb0768> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x18f6b0000 - 0x18f6bffff MobileKeyBag arm64  <0e6f9d62dfe23cbca54b4d1a14f76149> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18f6fc000 - 0x18f6fffff MobileSystemServices arm64  <54153419dcaa356fb42fd86b712a4cf2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x18f728000 - 0x18f739fff MobileWiFi arm64  <b033fc6a7d7b39debe0d81296dce51e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x18f790000 - 0x18f998fff MusicLibrary arm64  <8febe3b9c72a311f9cf0f8a95e52b821> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x18fab0000 - 0x18fab6fff Netrb arm64  <28eb6839c8f63101816697fa19770689> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x18fab8000 - 0x18fabffff NetworkStatistics arm64  <b120e0e7ff6d36889b917c7ca2e5f978> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x18fac0000 - 0x18fae2fff Notes arm64  <685e6f78db0e3adf9f233115bef345b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x18faec000 - 0x18faeffff OAuth arm64  <e8987386b74a365582fa85fef51bc127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x1902b8000 - 0x190306fff OpenCL arm64  <9ad1144d2c4333b980276e2c4e6ac4fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x190468000 - 0x190491fff PersistentConnection arm64  <6723595bce1937c3a45fbb85baff8c55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x190928000 - 0x190975fff PhysicsKit arm64  <6a97907da3523632b9e4848047aa8f4a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x190978000 - 0x190992fff PlugInKit arm64  <abb4118758ff3394be7af8851961f0a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit
0x190994000 - 0x19099cfff PowerLog arm64  <e938cd724d08330995b5f601f8dd14f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x190d14000 - 0x190dd5fff ProofReader arm64  <5d4f70ce92443a24b01e5c2186abfb15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x190dd8000 - 0x190e05fff ProtectedCloudStorage arm64  <d928e44bb8ce3522a7bb283faaa5047b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/ProtectedCloudStorage
0x190e08000 - 0x190e16fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <479705f12ac2303b931994a7b06663bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x190e58000 - 0x190ed6fff Quagga arm64  <66a25218aec23c18b9a18d8f810c5258> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x190ed8000 - 0x190ee1fff QuickLookThumbnailing arm64  <195ff028b269356eab3e5b1ba59f59ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/QuickLookThumbnailing.framework/QuickLookThumbnailing
0x191180000 - 0x191228fff SAObjects arm64  <56ba1d3456133884a61b2dd27ca74be2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x191410000 - 0x191430fff SpringBoardServices arm64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get a better log.

Try these steps

[App get Rejected: crashes on launch , but worked fine for me on all devices as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473575/app-get-rejected-crashes-on-launch-but-worked-fine-for-me-on-all-devices-as-w)

Get the .ipa file that you submitted to the app store.

Rename the extention .ipa with .zip , extract it. You'll get a Payload Folder which contains .app file.
Create a folder with this .app file and crash log file.
Now, open terminal application and go to the folder created in above step (using cd command).
Run this magic line :

atos -arch armv7 -o YourAppName.app/YourAppName MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH
Where, MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH = location where your app crashed as per the report.

Comment: Check out this answer for a more UI-intuitive approach
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28577267/1463604