# App crash on Apple review - I can't reproduce it

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I tested app on 10 different iOS devices, with and without Internet connection, with direct build and with Testflight build - app works. I tried different language settings, different regional settings - it works.

When I submit it for review it gets rejected for reason "Performance - 2.1" - app crash for them on first view.

Here is crash log Apple review team sent:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000a5d6c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   App name                        0x00000001000a5d6c 0x100050000 + 351596
1   App name                        0x00000001000a2dac 0x100050000 + 339372
2   UIKit                           0x00000001882f0be8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100
3   UIKit                           0x00000001882f0b64 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4   UIKit                           0x00000001882d8870 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 436
5   UIKit                           0x00000001882f0454 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
6   UIKit                           0x00000001882f0084 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804
7   UIKit                           0x00000001882e8c20 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784
8   UIKit                           0x00000001882b904c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
9   UIKit                           0x00000001882b7628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6568
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018311909c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183118b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183116830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183040c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
14  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184928088 GSEventRunModal + 180
15  UIKit                           0x0000000188322088 UIApplicationMain + 204
16  App name                        0x0000000100086d1c 0x100050000 + 224540
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182bde8b8 start + 4
```

Whatever I try (as described at top of question) I can't make app crash. I really can't figure out what is different in settings that they use on their test devices and in settings on devices I use for test (please note again: I'm not testing on one or two - I tested on 10 devices). I also tried on several last versions of iOS and (of course) on version 9.3.3 they use for test - it works.

I would really appreciate some advice regarding crash log here or how to make some configuration to make this app crash (so I can debug it).

Comment: what is you xcode version

Comment: @wg_hjl Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Comment: are you sure american connect your service will？

Comment: I think you can contact them and ask for more information, else you can try use Crashlystic and Answer to get the crash and device info

Comment: @Tj3n I opened TSI, they just send links to Apple docs on how-to debug and they haven't gave me any useful info... Crashlytics don't show anything which is weird...

Comment: Maybe they see crash then instant reject, Crashlystic required reopen the app or maybe it crashed before it initialized, but based on the log seems like they do some touch action already mean it should be initialized already...

Comment: what are the first 2 lines in the stack trace - which part of your app code is it - show that code, at least give us some details about the app to think about...

Comment: You need to symbolicate your crashlog.  Currently there is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: sometime very common mistake make app crash.Does your app have push notification enable?

Comment: Check below link it may be help you out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473575/app-get-rejected-crashes-on-launch-but-worked-fine-for-me-on-all-devices-as-w

Comment: It would be better if you post their comment from Resolution centre as well. Another thing you can make a call to them(support centre), they will guide you to reproduce crash. Though if you don't understand you can ask for more information in Resolution Centre as well.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: Have you tried on iOS 10?

Comment: Symbolicating your crashlog is must, please update with symbolicated crash log. Moreover, please post the code where you are using "UIControl", there might be a bug in it.

Comment: As other developers says: you have to symbolicate your crashlog to have a better understanding of the issue. Please take a look at this [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) (and go to the "Symbolication" part)